# I'm trying to make a void to check if something is true, and if something is, make a string say something depending on what was true

Tags: java

```
     public void sortingFamilyName(Player player) {
  if (player.Zamorak == true) {
   godFamily = "Zamorak";
  }
  if (player.Saradomin == true) {
   godFamily = "Saradomin";
  }
  if (player.Guthix == true) {
   godFamily = "Guthix";
  }
  if (player.Zaros == true) {
   godFamily = "Zaros";
  }
  if (player.Seren == true) {
   godFamily = "Seren";
  }
  if (player.Bandos == true) {
   godFamily = "Bandos";
  }
  if (player.Armadyl == true) {
   godFamily = "Armadyl";
  }
 }
```

Theres smallish trouble. It doesn't work. How can I make it so, if Armadyl is true, godFamily would be "Armadyl"?

Comment: please use `code-format`, also a dump of "player" would be helpful

Answer (score 3):

First, it is my opinion that you should really be using `Enum`s instead of `boolean` variables to determine the family of a given player. Then, you would compare your `Enum` variable `player` with `Player.Armady1`, like so:

```
 if (player == Player.Armadyl) {  
   godFamily = "Armadyl";  
 }
```

Also, you should use `else if`, so that when you match a family name, you don't do any more comparisons.

Moreover, you can also define the `toString` method in your `Enum`, thus avoiding the `if chain` that you have:

```
public enum Player {
  ZAMORAK { public String toString() { return "Zamorak"; } },
  ARMADY { public String toString() { return "Armady1"; } } 
}
```

Now, if you want to get the description of a given player, you just invoke its `toString` method.

Comment: Umm. Incompatible operand types Player and boolean

Comment: Can you explain how this enum thing works. Never seen this kind of thing before... or link me to somewhere where I could read about it...

Comment: Sure, take a look at `http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html` and `http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/JavaenumCreatinganEnum.htm`. Basically, you define a type (like a class) which holds a fixed set of constants. It is perfect for your situation, because you have a fixed set of values. Then, you can even add methods to it, just like you do with classes.

Comment: Thx! I'ma see what else I can do with enums :D

Answer (score 1):

While I've not seen all of your code, it looks like you might benefit from using an enum for family name rather than a bunch of boolean fields. You'd just have a Player.familyName field (or whatever you want to call it) with the type of the FAMILY_NAME enum you define.

Answer (score 0):

where does that boolean come from? i would change that, so instead of setting the boolean to true directliy write the string player.godFamily and check that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be using `else if` instead of `if` for all but the first one. In your code if more than one is `true` then godFamily will be set to the last true one.

Comment: Currently, it doesn't set it to ANY at all.